# get error in MediaRecorder in android 7.1.1

Tags: android, audio-recording, mediarecorder

I want to record voice by click on a button in my app. It works fine in most of android api but I get error in start of recording in api 25 (android 7.1.1).
how can I fix this issue?

this is my code :

```
private void startRecording() {
        try {
            audioRecordedFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/MyApp/Audio/Recording/";
            File recordingDir = new File(audioRecordedFileName);
            if (!recordingDir.exists())
                recordingDir.mkdirs();

            audioRecordedFileName += "voice_recording_" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(new Date()) + ".3gp";
            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
            recorder.setOutputFile(audioRecordedFileName);
            recorder.prepare();
            recorder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Recording", "prepare() failed:" + e);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Recording", "prepare() failed:" + e);
        }
    }
```

I get this error :

```
E/MediaRecorder: start failed: -2147483648
E/Recording: prepare() failed:java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
```

Thanks in advance.